# Add and init jQuery Datepicker inside jQuery Dialog on the go

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am creating a jQuery dialog upon a button click and the datepicker text boxes too are created inside the dialog box cloned from another DIV but when I click the text boxes the datepickers do not pop up as expected.

[image]

```
<div id='searchdialog'>blank div</div>
<div id='search'>
    <input type='text' id='arrivDate' />
    <input type='text' id='deparDate' />
</div>
<button id="popup" onclick="setPopupForm()">Click</button>

function setPopupForm(){
    $('#searchdialog').html($('#search').html());
    $('#searchdialog').find('#arrivDate').attr('id','arrivDate2');
    $('#searchdialog').find('#deparDate').attr('id','deparDate2');

    $('#searchdialog').dialog({
        height: 280,
        width: 740,
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        draggable: true
    });

    $('#arrivDate2').datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+7",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
    });
}
```

search - DIV that already exists

searchdialog - contents of the 'search' is added to this DIV and change the textbox ids to 'arrivDate2' and 'deparDate2'

When a button is clicked the function "setPopupForm()" is triggered and the dialog pops up. but when I click 'arrivDate2', datepicker does not open. I tried to init the picker inside the dialog but still does not work.

Please help me to figure this out.

here is the JSFIDDLE for the above I tried.
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/teshan87/yMYBS/2/)

Here is the real example I'm working on. Im trying to clone the contents in Find Hotel into a dialog and create another two datepickers by changing the new content ids on the go.
[EXAMPLE](http://www.miamisouthflorida.com/miami-hotels)

Comment: What are the relative z-indexes of the datepicker and the dialog?

Comment: Made a fiddle to reproduce it: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/2J4eQ/. I noticed that if I click outside the input field and then click inside, the datepicker appears.

Comment: @Barmar and if you add `$('#arrivDate').blur().focus();` at the end it opens itself by default

Comment: I think this is because "arrivDate" bydefault having focus.
If you can set default focus to some another field then your problem can be solved.
i have updated your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2J4eQ/1/

Comment: @Sandeeproop yes. `dialog` does that by default.

Comment: Here is the exact example for how my code should be. http://jsfiddle.net/teshan87/yMYBS/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
var content = "<div><input type='text' id='arrivDate' /></div>";
    $('#searchdialog').html(content);
    $('#arrivDate').datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+7",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
    });
    $('#searchdialog').dialog({height: 280, width: 740, resizable: false, modal: true, draggable: true});
```

first call datepicker for arrivDate then call searchdialog for dialog..

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KWLWH/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You could try with simply applying `blur` to the input

```
var content = "<span id='lala'></span><div><input type='text' id='arrivDate' /></div>";
$('#searchdialog').html(content).blur();
$('#searchdialog').dialog({
    height: 280,
    width: 740,
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    draggable: true
});
                /* Here it is */
                /****/
$('#arrivDate').blur().datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+7",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
});
```

**[UPDATED FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/2J4eQ/3/)**